# Extracting out year between parenthesis python

Tags: python

I will like to ask if I have a text here

```
a ="this car(chevelon) is manufactured in China(2012)"
b = "BMW was manufactred in Singapore(2014)"
c = "(2012) was the manufactured date of Ford"
```

I am trying to extract just the year.

I tried doing this but it gives me the first part chevelon

```
re.search(r'\((.*?)\)',title).group(1)
```

Do any of you have any idea how to go about this?

Comment: `r'\((\d*?)\)'` should do it.

Comment: @Graipher Should probably use `\d{4}`, instead, to avoid matching `()` or `(12345)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
re.sub(u'[()]', '', re.search(u"[(]\d{4}[)]", "this car(chevelon) is manufactured in China(2012)").group(0))
```

Will O/P -

```
2014
```

Reason for this pattern is -

```
[(]\d{4}[)]
```

We need to make sure our four digits are between the parentheses

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

In my Code, I am first finding all the numbers in the string, then it's stored in a list. After that, I am iterating through the list and finding the stored numbers' `len`. If it's `len` is equal to 4 then it is being stored, if not then it is not being stored. Here's the Code:

```
import re
a = "this car(chevelon) is manufactured in China(2012)"
finder = re.findall(r'\d+', a)
store_1 = [x for x in finder if len(x) == 4]
print(store_1)
```